# Store form data in Local Storage and display in table

Tags: javascript, json

How to store form input data? How to get it back and take actions like update, delete and clear?

Storing data using localStorage.setItem();
Getting data using localStorage.getItem();
I am taking user input and trying to save locally using JSON. Want to get data using JSON parse save it in table form. Want to take some actions like ADD Data, DELETE data on click. Clear the table using clear data () function. So I have related functions.
I am new. Didn't understand the logic completely.

**HTML FORM:**

```
<form id="form">
    <label for="fname">First name:  
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder 
     ="name">
    </label><br>
  
    <label for="lname">Last name:
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br>
    </label><br>
      
    <button class="btn">Add</button>
    <button class="btn">Clear List</button>
</form>       
        
<table id="myTable">
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th> 
          <th> Action</th>
      </tr>
      <tableBody id="tabledata">
      <tr>
        <td>cc </td>
        <td> qq </td> 
        <td><button class="btn">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tableBody>
</table>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
  let myfName = document.getElementById("fName").value; 
  let mylName = document.getElementById("lName").value;  
         
       if(localStorage.getItem('itemJson') == null){
                itemJsonArray =[];
                itemJsonArray
                .push([ myfName, mylName]);
                localStorage.setItem('itemJeson', 
               JSON.stringify(itemJsonArray))
                }
            else{
                itemJsonArrayStr 
              localStorage.getItem('itemJeson');
                itemJsonArry = JSON.parse(  
              itemJsonArrayStr);
                
               itemJsonArray
                .push([ myfName, mylName]);
                localStorage.setItem('itemJeson', 
               JSON.stringify(itemJsonArray))
              }
         
update();
      // updating inputs in table   
     function update(){ 
         if(localStorage.getItem('itemJson') == null){
             itemJsonArray =[];
             localStorage.setItem('itemJeson', 
             JSON.stringify(itemJsonArray))
            }
            else{
                itemJsonArrayStr = 
                localStorage.getItem('itemJeson');
                itemJsonArry = JSON.parse(  
                itemJsonArrayStr);
               }
         let tableData document.getElementById("tabledata");
         let str = "";
            itemJsonArray.forEach((element, index) => {
                
       str += ` <tr>
        <th scope="row"> ${index}</th>
         <td> ${element[0]}</td>
          <td> ${element [1]}</td>
          <td><button  class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" onclick = "deleted(${index}" >Delete</button></td>
                    </tr>`;
            }); 
       tablebody.innerHTML = str;
            
        }
           
      let add = document.getElementById("addItem");
      add.addEventListener("click", getAndUpdate);
            
 update();
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

</style>

<div id="result"></div>
<input id="data"></input>
<input type="date" id="date" name="date" value="2018-07-22" min="2018-01-01" max="2018-12-31">
<button onclick="Submit()">Submit</button>
<button onclick="Clear()">Clear</button>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>SL. NO</th>
    <th>Task Name</th>
    <th>Date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id ="tbl_data">
  </tr>
  <tr>
</table>

<script>
// Check browser support

var taskData = [];
var i = null;
function Submit(){
    if(taskData.length > 0){
        var data = document.getElementById('data').value;
        var date = document.getElementById('date').value;
        const obj = { "data": data , "date": date}
        var stored = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("task"));
        stored.push(obj);
    }
    var data = document.getElementById('data').value;
    var date = document.getElementById('date').value;
    const obj = { "data": data , "date": date}
    taskData.push(obj);
    
    localStorage.setItem("task", JSON.stringify(taskData));
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("task");
    
        if(i==null){
            i= 0;
        }
    
    for ( i = i; i < taskData.length; ++i) {
    
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
     var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        row.insertCell(0).innerHTML= i+1;
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= taskData[i].data;
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML= taskData[i].date;
    i=i;
        
    }
    
}
  // Retrieve
  
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in case it doesnot work here you can test it https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_compiler here